# show annotation on missing data point

Tags: dygraphs

Everything is working good with everything, but I have a run into a spot I am not sure if possible to do.

I am pulling data from a mysql database for results for every hour, but sometime nothing goes on for that hour and the database row is left empty for that hour. I wanted to put a annotation on events, but found that if there is no result in the data at that point the annotation doesn't show. Is there a way to get it to show if there is data or not at that point?

Data
[0,12][1,5][3,54][4,34]

Labels: ["time","number"]

Want to show a annotation where time would be 2.

Comment: That doesn't work. Where would you expect dygraphs to draw the annotation if there's no data point?